# Dynamic input calendar fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know this type of question is already asked but for my case i have problem with a bootstrap datepicker that can not display after add a new range of fields on click. The first calendar pops up properly how can i make the calendar pops up when it duplicates ?

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<label>Fecha de la consulta</label>
<div class="input-group date fecha_consulta1"  data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fecha[]" id="fecha" readonly required>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
<div><input type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="mytext3[]"></div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
x++; //text box increment
$(wrapper).append('<div><div class="input-group date fecha_consulta"  data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fecha[]" id="fecha" placeholder="fecha1'+ x +'" readonly required><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span></div><input type="text" name="mytext2[]" placeholder="field2'+ x +'"/><input type="text" name="mytext3[]" placeholder="field3'+ x +'"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
}
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: This is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ankit29/pzwoj491/6/.  The fisrt calendar is not diplayed but it's in my codes. My issue is with the duplicate calendars.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to solve my issue like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <form method="post" action="info.php">
 <div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="mytext[]" value="" size="10" /><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</div>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="mytext[]" value="" size="10" /><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
});

  $('.datepicker').live('click', function() {
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",yearRange: "1900:+10",showOn:'focus'}).focus();
});
});
```